# Time Stamp Question

Tags: c++, timestamp

I got a time stamp string as this `3.44063E+08`. How can I convert it to normal time, such as 12:10:22, etc.

Comment: Where did you get the time stamp?  _How_ did you get the time stamp?  Or, in other words, please show what you already have.

Comment: I get if from a winxp system application log file

Comment: Where did you get the timestamp from? What kind of application? What kind of function call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numeric value is a `time_t`, you need to convert it to local or Greenwhich time which `localtime()` or `gmtime()`, respectively, after which you can use `strftime()` to print in a format you choose.

Here is a quick and complete example:

```
edd@max:/tmp$ cat timeformat.c 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    time_t tt = 3.44063E+08;
    struct tm tm;
    char buf[32];

    tm = *localtime(&tt);

    strftime(buf, 31, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
edd@max:/tmp$ gcc -o timeformat timeformat.c 
edd@max:/tmp$ ./timeformat 
1980-11-25 23:03:20
edd@max:/tmp$
```

*Edit:* And as you tagged your question C++, have a look at [Boost Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/date_time.html) which has a lot to offer to.  But as my example showed, for the simple 'number to text' conversion, you do not need it.

Answer (score 1):

A timestamp in exponential format means that someone was using floating point time counters and wasn't paying attention when they wrote the code to print it. If all you have is that piece of text, you're not going to be able to convert it to an accurate time, since it's only accurate to 1000 seconds (about 20 minutes). If you actually have the original as a double, you can get an accurate time from it. If you have it as a float, god help you.

The number is (probably) a time_t, which is a count of seconds since the Unix epoch (1 January 1970). You can convert it to a broken-down time structure (year, month, etc) using gmtime() or localtime(), and then to whatever text format you want using strftime(). If you only have the text rather than an actual number, you'll have to parse it to a number first using strtod().

Answer (score 1):

A lot more context would be useful, but assuming you already have it, 3.44063E+08 is 344063000 which, as a time_t converts to 1980-11-26 05:03:20 (utc).  If that makes sense to you as a timestamp, then it is a time_t: number of seconds since 1970-01-01.

Another possibility is that it came from Excel or another Microsoft Office product, which stores dates as days since 1900, or 1899 in some cases.  That converts to some date in the year 943,893.  If that makes sense, like if you are doing astronomical or slow radioisotope calculations, etc., then it is early in the day, about 03:42.